# Render does not run action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using almost the code from the regular scaffold. The only change is the 4.times block where I make 4 answer objects on the question. The reason is that I have the corresponding input fields in the view. Now, if the validation fails it renders the new.html.erb again, however after what I have been reading it does not invoke the "new" action again. However I am depending on the 4.times block because otherwise the loop in the view have no answers to loop through. How do I fix this? I tried redirecting but then the error messages disappered.

New action

```
def new
    @question = Question.new

    4.times do
      @question.answers.build
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @question }
    end
  end
```

Create action

```
def create
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @question, status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as your title suggests: `render` does just render (the template belonging to) the action and not perform the action itself.

To get your prebuilt answers rendered again in a failed create call, I suggest removing the `:reject_if` condition from the nested attributes setup. This way, empty submitted answers are preserved. To prevent them from being written to the database, just add regular validations to the Question model...

Comment: Hi, but I have 4 input fields..and the user may not always have 4 answers, it might be only 2 so wouldn't checking for presence of the answer text fail if the user don't fill out all 4?

Comment: I solved it. I added a callback and removed the reject if condition.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look at is the `@question` in your create action. In theory it should contain the 4 newly built answers so redisplaying the form would also contain these.

If they are not written you may have to look at the [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) to make sure it gets deserialized correctly from the request.

Comment: I have this: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => :reject_empty_answers` and the method check if the description field is blank. So should I add a callback instead so it doesn't remove the empty answers from the question object? And only strip the emtpy answers when the object is saved correctly.